# HTML form submits values and stores all of them in a new array(javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, local-storage

I am trying to make a form with one text input and a submit button. What I want the script to do is take the text after I click submit and store it as a value. After that, if I type something else (without refreshing the page) and click submit store the input as another value. This process can be done one hunded times so I will have 100 different values. What I also want to do with this values is put them in a new array.So:
`var AllValues = [""+Val1+"",""+Val2+"",""+Val3"",..,""+Val99+"",""+Val100""];`.
The code I have managed to write untill now is this but it won't actually help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form1">
Type the words here: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction2()" value="Print all inserted words at array">
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {

}
function myFunction2() {
 var AllValues = [""+Val1+"",""+Val2+"",""+Val3"",..,""+Val99+"",""+Val100""];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = AllValues;  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am asking this question after trying a lot of things which didn't worked and I know that the script will work only if I use HTML local storage but I don't have the knowledge to do it even if I did a lot of research on this topic. I dont want to only store the values but I want to get them inside a new Array. I am making the question a bit more general as always in order to help as many as possible. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a very basic way of doing this, try the following:

HTML:

```
<form id="form1">Type the words here:
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit">
</form>
<input type="button" class="show-button" value="Print all inserted words at array">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

JS:

```
var values = new Array();

$(".submit").on("click", function () {
    values.push($('input[name="fname"]').val());
});

$(".show-button").on("click", function () {
    $("#demo").html(values.join("<br>"));
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5z4g04js/2/

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really helped me a lot. Do you know how can I make a button which clears the array(deletes all the values stored)?

Comment: use `array_name.length = 0`. I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5z4g04js/3/

Answer (score 2):

You had several issues, the main is that you have to provide the "id" attribute for the input text named "fname". 
Next you have to store the AllValues array in context visible by two declared functions (in this case, the global context).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form1">
Type the words here: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction2()" value="Print all inserted words at array">
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var AllValues = [];
function myFunction() {
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    AllValues.push(fname);
}
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = AllValues;  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Try also the immediate function to avoid storing variables in global context. The code that I paste is not very clean of course, but working :)

Comment: One fix you and the original question need is the handler declaration. `onclick="myFunction()"` assigns the click handler to the _result of calling myFunction_ — while `onclick="myFunction"` assigns the function named _myFunction_ as the handler.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery to do that:

```
var all_values =[];

    function myFunction() {
    var temp_val = $("#fname").val();
        alert(temp_val);
        all_values.push(temp_val);
    }


    function myFunction2() {
    alert(all_values);
    }

<form id="form1">
Type the words here: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction2()" value="Print all inserted words at array">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cbk5ymxd/)

p.s. edited jquery answer with more changes. [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d5LLye4r/)

Comment: If you're using jQuery to do that you ought to attach the click handlers the "right" way. Inline `onclick="function"` handlers are _not_ the way to go.

Comment: At this point there is an already writen code, and i make only the necessary changes. If it was mine i would use the .click() handler. Either way plz elaborate on the right way, after all we are on a learning site :)

Comment: Yes, I meant jquery `.click()` or `.on("click", ...)` and just thought if you were going from the OP plain JS to jQuery you might want to use a full jquery solution. I would have said the same thing on Thomas Weglinski's answer but that had _very_ minimal changes and stayed with plain JS.

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

```
<form id="form1">
Type the words here: <input id="words" type="text" name="fname"><br>
<input type="button" id="submitWords" value="Submit">
</form>
<input type="button" id="printWords" value="Print all inserted words at array">
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var arrWords = [];
var btnSubmit = document.getElementById('submitWords');
var btnPrint = document.getElementById('printWords');
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');

btnSubmit.onclick = function() {
  var words = document.getElementById('words').value;
  arrWords = words.split(' ');
  console.log(arrWords);
}

btnPrint.onclick = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < arrWords.length; i++) {
     demo.innerHTML += arrWords[i]+"<br>";
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this getAllValues(name) function, you can return the values of any element with the name of 'name'.

```
function getAllValues(name) {
  var nameMatches=document.getElementsByName(name);
  var AllValues=[];
  for (var i=0; i<nameMatches.length; i++) {
    AllValues.push(nameMatches[i].name);
    AllValues.push(nameMatches[i].value);
  }
  return AllValues;
}
```

To call this you would use `getAllValues('fname')`.